# How can I add a record with a foreign key using entity framework?

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to add records to my database through XML files like this one:

```
<Answers ExamID="1" StudentID="abcd" Date="10/26/2011 11:50:34 AM" Seed="495"
      IsSED="False">
  <Summary>
    <Objective ID="1" MakeUp="False" Quantify="5" Difficulty="Easy"
         Accredited="True" Produced="True">
      <Details Result="0" Date="10/26/2011 11:35:18 AM" />
      <Details Result="1" Date="10/26/2011 11:50:34 AM" />
    </Objective>
    <Objective ID="2" MakeUp="True" Quantify="5" Difficulty="Easy"
         Accredited="False" Produced="True">
      <Details Result="0" Date="10/26/2011 11:35:18 AM" />
      <Details Result="0" Date="10/26/2011 11:50:34 AM" />
    </Objective>
  </Summary>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="1" IsCorrect="True" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="9" />
  </Answer>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="1" IsCorrect="True" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="20" />
  </Answer>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="1" IsCorrect="True" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="16" />
  </Answer>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="1" IsCorrect="True" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="36" />
  </Answer>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="1" IsCorrect="True" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="18" />
  </Answer>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="2" IsCorrect="False" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="Null" />
  </Answer>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="2" IsCorrect="False" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="Null" />
  </Answer>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="2" IsCorrect="False" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="Null" />
  </Answer>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="2" IsCorrect="False" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="Null" />
  </Answer>
  <Answer ProblemID="0" ObjectiveID="2" IsCorrect="False" Difficulty="Easy">
    <Result DataType="System.Decimal" Value="Null" />
  </Answer>
</Answers>
```

Please, check the diagram. I need to get some data to add records to EXAM PRODUCED, EXERCISE AND  ANSWER tables (entities).

In EXAM PRODUCED, I've got a field called ExamID hide. My main problem is, how can I to reference the current file to the exam?

Do you think I need to create a stored procedure and SQL SERVER must do this?
Or using Linq to SQL?

I'm a bit confused with this situation.

[image]

Comment: Registries = records, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `ExamProduced` instance to the `ExamsProduced` collection of `Exam`. The DbContext will set the ExamId on insert.

Comment: And ExamProduced instance should be added in ExamsProduced table right?